# skin lesion: outpatient surgery and used antibiotic therapy diagnosis for a scars or ...?

Tags: scar-tissue-scars

this skin lesion is related to a 29-year-old girl who suffered from a carbuncle in the left  lower quadrant skin of abdomen about 10 years ago then replaced it with outpatient surgery and used antibiotic therapy and has now developed a wound with no pain.
in deep touch the lesion is mobile and painless 5 mm mass.
what it can be?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCK4x.jpg[image][image]

Comment: I think would be better if you ask a doctor personally